# Word 2013 Crash on Find.Execute

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, vsto, word-2013

I'm using VSTO ThisAddIn and Word 2013.

I want to replace all occurences of the one string with another using `Find.Execute` and mark this action with custom undo message. The code is:

```
application.UndoRecord.StartCustomRecord("Some Message");

var find = application.ActiveDocument.Content.Find;
find.Execute("string to be replaced"
  , ReplaceWith: "second string"
  , Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);

application.EndCustomRecord();
```

So I have a Word Crash during this code run. If I change `Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll` to `Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceOne`, I'll have word working, but I need to replace all occurrences.

Any suggestions/workarounds?

Comment: This is likely related to the document in question and not a general issue. It might be that there is an issue with a particular formatting or Word feature being used in the document. You can try to narrow things down be removing things from the document until the macro works.

Comment: Thanks for idea, but I just tried to do it with a new empty document and It crashed either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's some issue with Word when you have an empty custom undo and do a replace all. I just ran into this issue today.

[This page](https://devwrench.wordpress.com/2016/08/19/fix-word-vba-crash-wdreplaceall/) explains it well.

Options

1. Replace one, then replace all
2. Workaround by making a change to the doc before replace all, then
   undoing that change
3. remove the custom undo

Comment: Yes, you are right. I went for option 1 lots time ago.